# How can I hide last hr within a map react?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to hide the last hr with a map render in react:

here is my code base:

```
{teamData.Events.map((event) => (
  <div className="content">
    {event.description}
    <hr />
  </div>
))}
```

here is my css :

```
  .content {
    padding: 1rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    letter-spacing: 0.15px;

    hr {
      border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
      border-top: none;
    }

    hr:last-of-type {
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    a {
      color: #2252b7;
    }
  }
```

I tried :last-child but it seems like not working in my code. How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if its the last item of the array while mapping:

```js
array.map((item, ndx) => {
  const isLast = events.length - 1 === ndx;

  return (
    <div className="content">
      {event.description}
      {!isLast && <hr />}
    </div>
  );
});
```

OR

```css
.content:last-child hr {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to get to the last of the hr, not last of it's children?

```
hr:last-of-type {
 display: none;
}
```

Comment: It still did not hide the last hr

Comment: What about border: none or visibility: hidden?

Comment: should work. Works when I try in codepen. Did you write it like hr:last-of-type{  visiblity: hidden} ? It needs to be by itself, not as a part of the hr css you already got

Comment: Just added it in my code but 3 of those seem is hide my first hr as well. Idk why

Comment: you have no closing tag on your content in your css